# A jar build from Intellij does not include InvalidArgumentException

Tags: java, exception, intellij-idea, jar

I try build a .jar-File from Intellij, which works just fine, including the execution.

However, I am not able to use the Java-Exception "InValidArgumentException" inside the code, running this results in:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\java" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -jar "C:\Einziger Arbeitsordner Windows\Fortsetzung Projekttagsprogramm Windows\Projekttagsprogramm-Schule\Testordner\Projekttagprogramm Schule.jar"
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javaws/exceptions/InvalidArgumentException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at V2.cMain.main(cMain.java:42)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javaws.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

This is my project structure, along with the arguments for the artifact:

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGZWi.png)

[Artefact-Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5DXL.png)

Everything else works just fine, I have tried to rearrange the code in many different ways.

If you need any more information, I will happily help out.

Thanks in Advance,
Aaron

Comment: Some libraries define `InvalidArgumentException` but the base Java one is [IllegalArgumentException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html).

Comment: Can you post the code of your `cMain class`, especially around line 42 where the error is originating from.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Replacing the former with the later worked out fine, my problem is solved. Any Ideas why this particular Item was broken ? Just in case this happens again, maybe there is a pattern worth noting.
Thanks for the quick help!